# My google map refreshes every time when I click on a marker

Tags: reactjs, refresh, react-google-maps

So when i click on a marker the map always refreshes, how can I prevent it? 
On clicking a marker will  render specific infos about that marker, but its always realoading and goes back to its defaultCenter.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
import maplayout from "./mapstyle.js";


class Map extends Component {
  state = { users: []};

  onClick = (data) => {
    this.props.onClick(data);
  };

  render() {
  const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 47.507589, lng: 19.066128 }}
        defaultZoom={13}
      >
        {this.props.users.map((element, index) => (
          <Marker
            key = {index}
            icon={require("../assets/seenpinkek.svg")}
            position={{ lat: element.latitude, lng: element.longitude }}
            onClick={() => this.onClick(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div className="mapCont" />}
          mapElement={<div className="map" />}
          disableDefaultUI={true}
          isMarkerShown
          onClick={this.onClick}>
        </GoogleMapExample>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Can you show us your `this.props.onClick(data);` function ?
I think it's because you have a setState somewhere.
When you call the setState function, the component is rerendering, it could be the reason of your refresh

Comment: Yes its in my parent class:
`onChild2ButtonClick = (dataFromChild2) => {
        this.setState({
          infoIndex: dataFromChild2
        });
      };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior since parent component state is getting updated. To prevent your map component from re-rendering, you could let React know (via [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) method) whether a component should be affected by change in state or props or not:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  // If shouldComponentUpdate returns false, 
  // then render() will be completely skipped until the next state change.
  // In addition, componentWillUpdate and componentDidUpdate will not be called. 
  return false;
}
```

or (to allow update when the data has actually changed):

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState) {
    return (this.state.users !== nextState.users);
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dw65mc)

The similar issue with a solution has been reported [here](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/220)